# Catching promise rejections

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have the following functions:

A thrid party promisified search(id) function taking an ID returning a promise and a data object with the results

I am wrapping that in a checkItemExists(id) function that runs a search(id) and returns true or false if it finds results.

This checkItemExists(id) function is wrapped by another function validateID(id) that performs some form logic such as enabling forms etc if the item is unique.

```
validateID(id) => {
  checkItemExists(id).then((response) => {
    if (response) {
      // perform some logic
    } else {
      // perform some logic
    }
  }).catch (err) {
    // catch the error, handle and log it
  }
}

checkItemExists (id) => {
  // third party promisified search function
  search(id).then((response) => response {
    const itemsFound = response.data.listItems.items.length
    itemExists = itemsFound > 0 ? true : false 
    return Promise.resolve(itemExists)
  }).catch(err) => {
    console.log("In check item exists")
    return Promise.reject(err)
  }
}
```

If I pass an empty id to the search function it returns a rejected promise.
This promise makes it to the catch block of checkItemExists and logs out "In check item exists".

However it also raises a "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection" error and doesn't pass the rejection all the way up to validateID which is where I would like to handle it.

If I wanted to have all error handling in validateID, what am I missing?

Comment: Note you don't need `Promise.resolve` or `Promise.reject` here.

Comment: since `checkItemExists` doesn't return anything, of course you can't catch anything when you call it ... try `return search(id).then`

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I agree the `return Promise.resolve` is unnecessary, but you either `return Promise.reject(err)` or `throw err` rather than just `return err` inside `catch` (since that would "handle" the error if you did that) - of course, if you didn't have the catch block at all in `checkItemExists` that would be better code :p

Comment: OP - what you fail to mention is, `checkItemExists(id).then` will always fail, since calling `checkItemExists(id)` doesn't return a Promise - unless of course, the code in the question is a poor representation of the code you are having an issue with

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks adding that return for search(id) fixed it and I'm handling the error in the right place now. I've removed the excess Promise.resolve too.